# cache setting in grails

Tags: caching, grails, associations, ehcache

My DataSource Config:

```
hibernate {
 cache.use_second_level_cache = true
 cache.use_query_cache = true
 cache.provider_class='org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider'
}
```

i have an entity named Category that can have one or more Categories (children)

```
class Category{
 int ordering
 static hasMany = [categories: Category]


 static mapping = {
    categories(sort: "ordering", order: "asc")
    sort "ordering"
    cache usage: 'nonstrict-read-write'
    categories cache: 'nonstrict-read-write'
}
```

When i change a property from the admin page, lets say the ordering property from a category instance, that change is not reflected from the association to the parent category, so the assoc collection has the old property for the altered child. 
I tried to remove this:

```
  categories cache: 'nonstrict-read-write'
```

and then the categories assoc is always up to dated.

How can i ensure that every time i update a category instance, the categories assoc for the parent category will be informed with the changes? Shouldnt be worked like this by default??

Answer (score 1):

ok i found it!
i had to evict the entire collection like this:
      sessionFactory.evictCollection(Category.class.name + '.categories')