# Cached association not get updated upon child item created

Tags: hibernate, caching, grails, ehcache, second-level-cache

Say, I have domain object

```
class Parent {
  static hasMany = [children:Child]
  static mapping = {
   cache true
   children cache: true // !!!
  }
}
```

I have admin page that shows Parent with list of children. 
Also there is an ability to add new child. 
What happens to me is when I add new child with line (!!!) enabled - child not appears on Parent page. Though it's added to DB, because server restart makes it show.
Without line (!!!) it works as expected.

Is this how it should work by design? 
Should I manually invalidate the association cache?
Also something similar is described in this question [cache setting in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719366/cache-setting-in-grails)

Grails documentation is not very informative on this http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#caching .

Btw. I'm using Grails 2.2.1.

Comment: Are the children something that almost never gets updated?

Comment: Yes. They configured by admin ones and then used mostly in read-only fashion, rearly updated.

Comment: Did you try the other cache settings? `read-write`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found the reason. Seems Hibernate works this way by design. It's described here http://planet.jboss.org/post/collection_caching_in_the_hibernate_second_level_cache

This part:

> What happens when a new Member is created and associated with a Group
>   whose members collection is cached? As I stated above, Hibernate
>   doesn’t update the collection in the cache, it just removes it. So,
>   we’d expect the collection to be removed. And it should be, but there
>   is an important subtlety that application developers need to be aware
>   of:
>
> Collections are only invalidated from the cache as a result of an
>   operation on the Java object that represents the collection!
>   Performing some Java operation that results in a change in the
>   database whereby a fresh read of the database would add the member to
>   the collection isn’t sufficient.

So the fix was to inject in Controller

```
def sessionFactory
```

and manually invalidate collections cache in save() method

```
sessionFactory.cache.evictCollectionRegions()
```

Comment: Thank you!This answer saved me so much time!

Answer (score 1):

`read-write` cache mode is set by default. Indeed you are not supposed to make any additional steps to work with second level cache. It should be fully transparent for users. The magic takes place behind your code. Did you turn on L2 cache in Grails configuration (DataSource.groovy)?

Comment: Yes, I configured Hibernate L2 cache using Ehcache